# WPF: dependency property with type of Template - where to get default template (to set as default value)?

Tags: wpf, templates, dependency-properties, default-value

I am subclassing an ItemsControl (let's call it EnhancedItemsControl), and I would like to expose ScrollViewerTemplate dependency property, which would allow the user to optionally specify his own template for used ScrollViewer. I am doing it like this:

```
public ControlTemplate ScrollViewerTemplate
{
   get { return (ControlTemplate)GetValue(ScrollViewerTemplateProperty); }
   set { SetValue(ScrollViewerTemplateProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollViewerTemplateProperty =
   DependencyProperty.Register(
   "ScrollViewerTemplate", 
   typeof(ControlTemplate), 
   typeof(EnhancedItemsControl),
   new UIPropertyMetadata(new ScrollViewer().GetValue(ScrollViewer.TemplateProperty))); //This doesn't work for me
```

In my default style for my EnhancedItemsControl, I then include the ScrollViewer like this:

```
<ScrollViewer
   Template="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewerTemplate}"
   ...
>
    <ItemsPresenter
    ...
    />
</ScrollViewer>
```

This works when the user specifies the ScrollViewerTemplate, but when he leaves it at default value, the ScrollViewer is not displayed (presumably because it's Template is empty). How can I tell WPF **Use the Template only when it is non-null, otherwise use default one**? (it occured to me that I could use triggers to set the Template only when it is not null, but I don't like the idea of having a trigger for every custom property in each of my controls...)

There is similar problem with styles - if I wanted to let user specify the ScrollViewer style, but the user didn't specify it, the value of ScrollViewerStyle would be null (equal to `<ScrollViewer Style="{x:Null}" />`), which would stop the default style from being applied!

How to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing everything right except one little bit, the default value you are specifying in your `UIPropertyMetadata` is actually null, because it's null in that new `ScrollViewer` as well by default.

Instead of defining a `ScrollViewerTemplate` property, define a `ScrollViewerStyle` property:

```
public Style ScrollViewerStyle
{
    get { return (Style)GetValue(ScrollViewerTemplateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ScrollViewerTemplateProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollViewerTemplateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ScrollViewerStyle", 
        typeof(Style), 
        typeof(EnhancedItemsControl), 
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

And in your default style for the control, specify a default value for the style as such:

```
<Setter Property="ScrollViewerStyle" Value="{StaticResource {x:Type ScrollViewer}}"/>
```

This will actually default to the ScrollViewer style as defined by the current theme.

Comment: Thank you, you're the man! I didn't know that I can get the default style from resource dictionary indexed by type, that's pretty unintuitive - thanks again for showing me, that's much better than assigning the style/template with trigger when they are not null.

Comment: While everything else is uncertain, one thing is sure, I am the man :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using TemplateBinding you can use Binding with RelativeSource of TemplatedParent. This way you will be able to use converter in your Binding. Now declare a Converter(IValueConverter) for your Binding and return the default Template while the ScrollViewerTemplate property is null.

[More Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I know about possibility of replacing the TemplateBinding with normal binding, but without Aviad's post I still wouldn't know how to get the default value of Template.